# Android: OpenCV: Use of Camera and CameraBridgeViewBase classes simultaneously, joint use issues

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera

I'm pretty new to Java and Android in general but have some good experience with C/C++.  I am trying to use multiple class files and multiple Camera APIs in the same application.

I am trying to build a panora application that gets the full resolution sensor data (I have an 8MP Nexus 5).  To the best of my knowledge and research, the CameraBridgeViewBase class' method onCameraFrame() basically downsamples the data to fit your device's screen resolution (in my case 1280x960).  I therefore cannot use it for what I'm trying to do; I need to use the Java Camera API instead.

I basically took the code [presented here](http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/12/21/panorama-app-on-android-using-stitching-module-opencv/), and reworked a couple things to try getting the full data.

The main java file:

```
package org.opencv.samples.tutorial3;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Sample3Native extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2{
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

    public static final int VIEW_MODE_RGBA = 0;
    public static final int SAVE_IMAGE_MAT = 1;
    public static final int CAPT_STILL_IM = 2;
    private static int viewMode = VIEW_MODE_RGBA;
//  public static int image_count = 0;
    private MenuItem mStitch;
    private MenuItem mItemCaptureImage;
    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGrayMat;
    private Mat panorama;
    private Mat mtemp;
    private List<Mat> images_to_be_stitched = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private long mPrevTime = new Date().getTime();
    private static final int FRAME2GRAB = 10;
    private int mframeNum = 0;
    private static final File tempImageDir = new                          File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "panoTmpImage");
    private static final File StitchImageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator  + "panoStitchIm");
    private static final String mImageName = "im";
    private static final String mImageExt = ".jpeg";
    private long recordStart = new Date().getTime();
    private static final long MAX_VIDEO_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 3 * 1000; // Convert milliseconds to seconds
    //private Sample3NativeCapturer imageCapturer = new Sample3NativeCapturer(getBaseContext(),1);

    //private Sample3Native_imgCapture imageCapturer;
//Had to insert to get it to work..
    public final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public 
    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateResultsInUi();
        }
    };


    private void updateResultsInUi()
    {

    }

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                //imageCapturer.enableView();
                //imageCapturer.setOnTouchListener( Sample3Native.this);
                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("native_sample");

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();

            }
                break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public Sample3Native() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial3_surface_view);


        final Button btnVidCapt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVidCapt);
        btnVidCapt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startVidCap();
            }
        });

        final Button btnStitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStitch);
        btnStitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stitchImages();
            }
        });

        final Button btnViewStitchedIm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewStitchedIm);
        btnViewStitchedIm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewStitchImages();
            }
        });
        //button I may have to modify when capturing an image..
        final Button btnCapStil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapStil);
        btnCapStil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captStillImage();
            }
        });
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial4_activity_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
//      imageCapturer = (Sample3NativeCapturer) findViewById(R.id.tutorial4_activity_surface_view);
//      imageCapturer.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
//      if (imageCapturer != null)
//      imageCapturer.disableView();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this,
                mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
//      if (imageCapturer != null)
//      imageCapturer.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        mGrayMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        mtemp = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        panorama = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
        mGrayMat.release();
        mtemp.release();
        panorama.release();
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inFrame) {
        Mat inputFrame = inFrame.rgba();
        inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);
        switch (Sample3Native.viewMode) {
        case Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA: {
            Core.putText(mRgba, "Video Mode", new Point(10, 50), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
            // Update start recordtime until starting recording
        }break;
        case Sample3Native.SAVE_IMAGE_MAT: {
            long curTime = new Date().getTime();
            Core.putText(mRgba, "Record Mode", new Point(10, 50), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
            long timeDiff = curTime - recordStart;
            Log.i("timeDiff", Long.toString(timeDiff));

            if ( timeDiff < MAX_VIDEO_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS) {
                if ((mframeNum % FRAME2GRAB) == 0) {
                    saveImageToArray(inputFrame);
                    mframeNum++;
                } 
                else
                    mframeNum++;
            } 
            else
            {
                mframeNum = 0;
                turnOffCapture();
            }
        }break;
        case Sample3Native.CAPT_STILL_IM :
        {
            saveImageToArray(inputFrame);

            //RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO MODIFY!  CAPTURE IMAGE
            //WITH THE CAMERA INSTEAD OF USING THE PREVIEW.
            //IF I CAN DO THIS, WE CAN GET AND STITCH FULL-RES IMAGES...
            //Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
//          Mat theImage = imageCapturer.getCapturedImage(1);
//          saveImageToArray(theImage);
            Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA;
        }
        }
        return mRgba;
    }

    public void startVidCap() {
        if (Sample3Native.viewMode == Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA)
        {
            turnOnCapture();
        }
        else if (Sample3Native.viewMode == Sample3Native.SAVE_IMAGE_MAT)
        {
            turnOffCapture();
        }
    }

    private void turnOffCapture()
    {   
//      Button startVidCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVidCapt);
        // Stop Recording
//      startVidCapture.setText("Start Video Capture");
        Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA; 
    }

    private void turnOnCapture()
    {
//      Button startVidCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVidCapt);
        // Start recording
        Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.SAVE_IMAGE_MAT; 
//      startVidCapture.setText("Stop Video Capture");
        images_to_be_stitched.clear();
        recordStart = new Date().getTime();

    }

    public void stitchImages() {
        if(!images_to_be_stitched.isEmpty())
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < images_to_be_stitched.size(); j++) {
                writeImage(images_to_be_stitched.get(j), j);
            }
        Log.i("stitchImages", "Done writing 2 disk. Starting stitching " + images_to_be_stitched.size() + " images");
            FindFeatures(images_to_be_stitched.get(0).getNativeObjAddr(),
                    images_to_be_stitched.get(0).getNativeObjAddr(),
                    panorama.getNativeObjAddr(), images_to_be_stitched.size());
        Log.i("stitchImages", "Done stitching. Writing panarama");
            writePano(panorama);

        Log.i("stitchImages", "deleting temp files");

            deleteTmpIm();
        }
    }

    public void captStillImage()
    {
        Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.CAPT_STILL_IM;

    }

    private String getFullFileName( int num)
    {
        return mImageName + num + mImageExt;
    }

/*  private void writeImage(List<Mat> imList) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (Mat im : imList) {
            String fileName = "/sdcard/im" + counter + ".jpeg";
//          Highgui.imwrite(s, images_to_be_stitched.get(j));
            counter++;
        }
    }
*/  
    private void writeImage(Mat image, int imNum)
    {
        writeImage(image, getFullFileName(imNum));
    }

    private void writeImage(Mat image, String fileName) {
        File createDir = tempImageDir;
        if(!createDir.exists())
            createDir.mkdir();
        Highgui.imwrite(tempImageDir+File.separator + fileName, image);
    }


    private void writePano(Mat image)
    {
        Date dateNow = new  Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        if(!StitchImageDir.exists())
            StitchImageDir.mkdir();
        Highgui.imwrite(StitchImageDir.getPath()+ File.separator + "panoStich"+dateFormat.format(dateNow) +mImageExt, image);

    }

    private void deleteTmpIm()
    {
        File curFile;
        for (int j = 0; j < images_to_be_stitched.size(); j++) {
            curFile = new File(getFullFileName(j));
            curFile.delete();
        }
        images_to_be_stitched.clear();
    }


    public void viewStitchImages() 
    {   
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content:" + StitchImageDir.getAbsolutePath()));//media/external/images/media"));
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void saveImageToArray(Mat inputFrame) {
    images_to_be_stitched.add(inputFrame.clone());
}

private int FPS() {
    long curTime = new Date().getTime();
    int FPS = (int) (1000 / (curTime - mPrevTime));
    mPrevTime = curTime;
    return FPS;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
    mStitch = menu.add("Stitch Images");
    mItemCaptureImage = menu.add("Capture Image");
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);

    return true;
}

// public native void FindFeatures(List<Long> pano_images, Long stitch );
public native void FindFeatures(long image1, long image2, long image3,
        int count);
```

}

The secondary file (instantiated in the first one):

```
package org.opencv.samples.tutorial3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
public class Sample3NativeCapturer extends JavaCameraView implements PictureCallback {

    public Sample3NativeCapturer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Sample3NativeCapturer(Context context, int camID){
        super(context,camID);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "Sample::Tutorial3View";
    private static int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private int interpBy = 1;
    private Mat theImage;




    public List<String> getEffectList() {

        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
    }

    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
    }

    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setColorEffect(effect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

    public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        //mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes()
    }

    public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
        mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    //Set CAPTURE resolution (currently only setting preview resolution)
    public void setCaptureResolution(Size resolution){
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setPictureSize(resolution.width,resolution.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

    public Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Taking picture");
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        try{
            params.setJpegQuality(100);
            params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        }finally{}
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class

        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    //@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
        //File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        try {
            //Now try to convert and save.
            Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            Size sz = params.getPictureSize();
            Mat raw = new Mat(1, data.length, CvType.CV_8UC1);
            raw.put(0, 0, data);
            theImage = Highgui.imdecode(raw, 0);

        } finally {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback");
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


       public Mat getCapturedImage(int interpVal){
           interpBy = interpVal;
           takePicture();
           return theImage;
       }

}
```

After debugging, I've found the problem comes from instantiating the second class in the line

```
private Sample3NativeCapturer imageCapturer = new Sample3NativeCapturer(getBaseContext(),1);
```

Which take a context and an integer as its settings.  It seems to be OK if I put it in the BaseLoaderCallback class, but if I put it where it is, it crashes and I can't even see what caused the crash in the debugger.  Maybe this isn't my problem?

I wonder if using this dual functionality (of `CameraBridgeViewBase` and the Camera API) is even possible, or should I just try to port everything over to the Camera API?  Again, I'm very new to Android so I would prefer avoiding that if there's an alternate solution.